# Unable to release Exoplayer from Memory

Tags: android-activity, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

I am using `Exoplayer` in the `Recyclerivew`. I want to release the `Exoplayer` on `Activity` destroy. I am using Exoplayer in the `ViewHolder`.I am not able to find any way to release the `Exoplayer`.

```
 public void releaseMemory() {
    audioCapabilitiesReceiver.unregister();//Method in the ViewHolder
    player.release();
}


 public void releaseMemory() {
    viewHolder.releaseMemory();//Method in the Adapter
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    videoAdapter.releaseMemory();//Method in the Activity
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Now I am getting the `RuntimeException`.Is there any other efficient way to do so.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.waynell.videolist.demo, PID: 22746
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.waynell.videolist.demo/com.waynell.videolist.demo.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3487)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3541)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:138)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.waynell.videolist.demo.activity.MainActivity.onStop(MainActivity.java:325)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1212)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5376)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3482)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3541) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:138) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop player onStop() method for an activity insteadOf onDestroy();

Comment: Need to lookup whole error logs to trace where it actually gives error

Comment: It is not full logs may be you are missing some logs

Comment: Is there any other better way to do so? I just want to release `Exoplayer` from the memory on Activity stop.

Comment: First check in onCreate();

Comment: audioCapabilitiesReceiver = new AudioCapabilitiesReceiver(this, this);
    audioCapabilitiesReceiver.register();

Comment: And in onDestroy();
audioCapabilitiesReceiver.unregister();
    releasePlayer();

Comment: I am using the Exoplayer in The Recyclerview ViewHolder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120510/discussion-between-nilaydani-and-shikha-ratra).